# Distance metric for comparing ingredient lists

Tags: python, similarity, hamming-distance, distance-matrix

I am using sklearn pairwise distances to identify the similarity of different products based on their ingredients.
My initial df looks like this and contains only 0s and 1s:

| Products | Ingredient 1 | Ingredient 2 | ... | Ingredient 500 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| Product 2 | 1 | 1 | ... | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Product 600 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |

I have converted this to a distance matrix to receive the distances for each pair of products based on their ingredients and calculated the distance matrix by running the following code:

```
X = df.to_numpy()
distance_array = pairwise_distances(X, metric='hamming')
```

I have selected hamming as metric based on this article https://towardsdatascience.com/9-distance-measures-in-data-science-918109d069fa as I would like to know the absolute number of ingredients that are different between each product pair. However the matrix returns floats like 0.006 for a product combination that differs only by one ingredient, but I would have expected it to return 1 in this case.

Can anyone help me out on this and explain why hamming distance is not returning the absolute numbers? Is there a more suitable metric for my Use Case?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It states "number of values that are different between two vectors", so yes you would expect to see `1` if only 1 ingredient differs, but the algorithm displays as a percent, not a count. So if 2 of the 3 values differ, that's .6667.

if you see `0`, that means no difference. If you see `1`, it means 100% difference (Ie all columns are different when compared.)

If you want the number of differences though, you'll need to multiple the values by the number of ingredients.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances


data = [
        [0,1,1],
        [1,1,0],
        [1,1,1],
        [0,1,1],
        [0,0,1]]

columns = ['Ing1', 'Ing2','Ing3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)


X = df.to_numpy()
distance_array = pairwise_distances(df, metric='hamming')

products = ['Product %s' %i for i in range(1, len(df) + 1) ]

distance_matrix = pd.DataFrame(distance_array)
distance_matrix.set_index = products
distance_matrix.columns = products

distance_matrix_vals = distance_matrix * len(columns)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]